# How to click a checkbox that's dynamically named/generated using Selenium IDE?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

How would I locate / click the following element in Selenium IDE? The text "Sample XYZ5" is dynamically generated. So is the value 99999.

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" value="99999" name="sample[]">
Sample #XYZ5
</td>
```

Because of the dynamic generation, the Selenium IDE 'record' function wasn't appropriate. It was only capturing the locator as 'name=sample[]' which can refer to any number of samples[] on this page.

This is a data driven test, so the text between the HTML tags can be read into a variable used by the Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selenium IDE normally has a recording function. With this function you should be able to record a click on your element. Then you only have to watch how the IDE records it.

But if you want to click on it using some other frameworks (like creating an automatic test in Java or Python or...) you should use XPaths to locate the element. But be aware of your XPath combination because if the element doesn't have an ID it's a little bit tricky to get a unique XPath.

Comment: Yes - I'm looking for possible xpath settings for the above HTML. The 'Record' capability has not worked for this situation. Selenium IDE accepts xpath values for locating elements but I'm having trouble with identifying an appropriate combination.

Comment: In this example the XPath could look like: "//td[@value_'99999']"

Comment: Thank you Pascal. The issue in this application is that the "value" attribute gets is dynamic and can't be provided to Selenium so the suggested xpath can't be built. The text value that follows the checkbox "Sample #XYZ5" is predictable can be supplied to Selenium. Hence, we need a way through xpath to find/select the checkbox that is part of the same <td> as the "Sample..." text. Any thoughts?

Comment: I got some thoughts of how you could solve this...
1.) try use an a XPath like: "td[@name='sample[]']" (only possible if it's the only element with the name sample[])
2.) use selectByVisibleText("sample #XYZ5") 
3.) if you choose 1.) and it's not the only but the first one with the given XPath use By.FirstByXpath(xpath)
4.) search here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html?overview-summary.html for any method which support your case
5.) use findElements() to get a list of elements and following sort this list with "normal functions" for your element

Comment: It looks like the coders have set it up so that there are multiple elements in that group of checkboxes named 'sample'. I'm trying to stick to the Selenium IDE because we need to train some end users in launching test cases and thus want to avoid command line Java. "selectByVisibleText" doesn't seem to show as available in the Selenium IDE. I'll get through this - your advice has helped me in other ways though and it will get used elsewhere.

Comment: Pascal, this XPATH works: //td[contains(.,'Sample #XYZ5')]/input[@type='checkbox'] Since it's based on your helpful advice, I've edited the above answer. Please accept my edits and then I'll accept your answer.